# Stationary phase method for two stationary points

Tags: asymptotics, stationary-point

I have a function $\psi(t)$ which has two stationary points at $t=a$ and $t=b$ and I want to find the asymptotic form of the integral
$I(x)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)e^{ix\psi(t)}dt$. Bender&Orzsag talks about the approximation around a single stationary point, namely the lower limit of the integral, but I'm not sure how to extend it to the case when both the limits are stationary points. Any help would be appreciated.
TIA!

Comment: Is the method applicable to $\int_a^{(a + b)/2}$ and $\int_{(a + b)/2}^b$?

Comment: @Maxim But the lower limit has to be a stationary point for it to work, right? (a+b)/2 is not a stationary point here

Comment: Is the method applicable to $\int_{-b}^{-(a + b)/2} f(-t) e^{i x \psi(-t)} dt$? :) The point is that the steps for approximating $\int_{b - \epsilon}^b$ are the same as for $\int_a^{a + \epsilon}$.